# How to exclude the cglib dependencies from an Android(Gradle) app?

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, cglib

I had an [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51604201/how-to-use-mongodb-morphia-on-android/51618069#51618069) with using MongoDB Morphia on Android which led me to [this post](https://github.com/mongodb/morphia/issues/954) where there is a sugestion to "exclude the cglib dependencies" from my app. How would I do that?

Answer (score 0):

By not adding it to the class path at runtime.

In Maven, you can [exclude dependencies](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-optional-and-excludes-dependencies.html) by the `<excludes>` tag within the dependency declaration.

Comment: Ups, added it as a tag but didn't specify on the description. I am using Gradle.

Comment: Actually I had indeed said it was an "Android app" but someone had edited it out.